# Java check if a boolean is initialized

Tags: java, initialization, boolean

I'm not talking about checking if a boolean is null as a means to check if it is initialized. Because that won't work. So I thought this might work:

```js
public class MyClass{

    private boolean setting;

    private boolean getSetting{
        // get the setting;
    }

    public void main{
        if (setting != (true && false))
            setting = getSetting();
        // do main stuff;
    }

}
```

And it does! So my question is: would this be a good practice compared to the alternative, which would be the use of an extra variable:

```js
public class MyClass{

    private boolean initialized = false;
    private boolean setting;

    private boolean getSetting{
        // get the setting;
    }

    public void main{
        if (!initialized)
            setting = getSetting();
            initialized = true;
        // do main stuff;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (setting != (true && false))` doesn't do what you think it's doing.

The expression `(true && false)` always evaluates to `false`: you're doing a logical AND on the literal values `true` and `false`.

That means that your test reduces to `if (setting != false)`. Since `setting` is not initialized, it defaults to `false`. When the code runs it checks `if (false != false)`, which evaluates to `false`.

When I run the code you posted it does not call `getSetting`, as expected.

In your example, best practice would be to initialize the variable inside the constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
    private boolean someSetting;

    public MyClass() {
        someSetting = getSetting();
    }

    private boolean getSetting() {
        ...
    }

    public void main() {
        // By the time this is called we can guarantee that someSetting has been initialized correctly
        // Do main stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that answers my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you click the 'accept answer' button on the answer that was most helpful to you. That will let people know that the question has been answered and help others to find the most useful answer quickly.

Comment: @CameronSkinner "Most useful" is very subjective. Read here (top-rated answer): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291531/im-fairly-new-here-but-it-seems-like-many-question-askers-only-want-the-line-o

Answer (score 5):

Booleans are a primitive type, therefore they do not need to be initialized. The default value for a boolean is `false`.

The first code sample returns false because the phrase `true && false` will always equate to false (`&&` checks whether both statements are true, which they aren't, so it is false) and then you check if `setting`, which is also `false`, is unequal to that, which it is not. An `initialized` variable could therefore be useful.

You can read more about defaults and primitive types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I see. Of course `if (setting != (true && false))` is the same as doing: `if (setting)`

Comment: @RafColson No, the first of those two options will always return true, as I explained in my answer (try thinking through it logically yourself. Plug in true and/or false and see what your result is). The latter will only execute if `setting` is true, which in your case it never will be (since you didn't initialize it to be true). I recommend writing `if(!setting) setting = getSetting();`

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, I mistakenly forgot the ! there. It's because in my project I'm having: `if (setting) return;` But I wanted to keep the example in my question simple. But thanks for explaining.

Comment: The first code sample will never call `getSetting`. `if (setting != (true && false)` does not check if setting equals both `false` and `true`; it checks if `setting` is not equal to the logical operation `true && false`. The expression `true && false` always evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Thank you for catching that! Funny thing is that I knew that too, but my head was just checking if `setting` could not be both true and false (which is what the OP was intending with his code).

Comment: But if a boolean has false as a default value, why does this not compile `Boolean b; System.out.println(b);`? (It fails with an error "B may no be initilized")?

Comment: @d-b `Boolean` is an object so it has to be initialized. `boolean` on the other hand is a primitive, so it defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `(setting != (true && false))` has already been discussed, but the real issue is that the primitive `boolean` only has its two obvious options.  It's always either `true` or `false`.  If both of those are meaningful answers, then that value cannot *also* indicate whether it's been initialized or not.  An initialized, meaningful `false` will look the same as not having been initialized.

The best solution if it's available is, as Cameron Skinner answered above, to ensure the variable is *always* initialized by doing so either where it's declared or in the constructor.  That, however, requires that the answer to what `setting` should be is known at the time the class is instantiated.

If the proper value is not necessarily known at that point and might need to be set later (so having been deliberately set to false is a different situation than having never been set), then you have a couple options:

One is as shown in the initial post, to have a separate `initialized` variable telling you whether it's happened or not.  That might look a little clunky, but it works.

The other option is to use a `Boolean` object rather than a `boolean` primitive for `setting`.  A `Boolean` object can be set to either `true` or `false`, but it initially defaults to `null`, so you can use a check for `null` to determine whether it has been set or not.